# Tableview Search Bar does not return detailTextLabel properly (Xcode - Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase

I'm quite new to Xcode so i don't really know much about search bar and tableviews. As of right now, the search bar is working properly just that it doesn't return the correct value of a specific booth when searching. Do look at the images for easier reference. Your help is really appreciated. Thank you!

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseDatabase

var ref: DatabaseReference?
var databaseHandle: DatabaseHandle?
var postData = [String]()
var postData2 = [String]()
var currentpostDataArray = [String]()
var tableDataArray = [tableData]()

class TableViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchBarDelegate {


    @IBOutlet var searchBar: UISearchBar!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setUpSearchBar()


        ref = Database.database().reference() //set the firebase reference

        // Retrieve the post and listen for changes
        databaseHandle = ref?.child("Posts2").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            // Code to execute when a child is added under "Posts"
            postData.removeAll()
            postData2.removeAll()
            tableDataArray.removeAll()

            for child in snapshot.children {
                let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
                let key = snap.key
                let value = String(describing: snap.value!)
                let rating = (value as NSString).integerValue

                postData.append(key)
                postData2.append(value)

                tableDataArray.append(tableData(boothName: key, boothRating: rating))
                currentpostDataArray = postData
            }

            self.tableView.reloadData()


        })

    }


    private func setUpSearchBar() {
        searchBar.delegate = self
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return currentpostDataArray.count
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

        cell.textLabel?.text = currentpostDataArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = postData2[indexPath.row] + " ♥"
        cell.detailTextLabel?.textColor = UIColor.red;
        return cell
    }

    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        currentpostDataArray = postData.filter({ (postdata) -> Bool in
            switch searchBar.selectedScopeButtonIndex {
            case 0:
                if searchText.isEmpty { return true }
                return postdata.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())
            case 1:
                if searchText.isEmpty { return true }
                return postdata.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())
            default:
                return false
            }
        })
        tableView.reloadData()
    }


        func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, selectedScopeButtonIndexDidChange selectedScope: Int) {
            switch selectedScope {
            case 0:
                currentpostDataArray.removeAll()
                postData2.removeAll()
                for data in tableDataArray {
                    currentpostDataArray.append(data.boothName)

                    let value = String(describing: data.boothRating)
                    postData2.append(value)
                }
                self.tableView.reloadData()

            case 1:
                currentpostDataArray.removeAll()
                postData2.removeAll()
                let sortedTableData = tableDataArray.sorted(by: { $0.boothRating > $1.boothRating })
                for data in sortedTableData {
                    currentpostDataArray.append(data.boothName)

                    let value = String(describing: data.boothRating)
                    postData2.append(value)
                }
                self.tableView.reloadData()

            default:
                break

            }
            tableView.reloadData()
        }

}

class tableData {
    var boothName: String
    var boothRating: Int
    init(boothName: String, boothRating: Int) {
        self.boothName = boothName
        self.boothRating = boothRating
    }
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: What is you expectation. Add some image of your expectation.

Comment: if you look closely at image 1, Booth 3 is supposed to have 6 hearts but return 38 hearts which belongs to Booth 1. I need the search bar to return the appropriate hearts to the booths

Comment: k got your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It is happening because in your code postData contains the key.**

```
 for child in snapshot.children {
            let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
            let key = snap.key
            let value = String(describing: snap.value!)
            let rating = (value as NSString).integerValue

            ***postData.append(key)***
```

**In**

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String)
```

You are returning the post-date contents, which contains only key no value. Here you are not updating postData2.

**So**

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel?.text = currentpostDataArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = postData2[indexPath.row] + " ♥" 
    cell.detailTextLabel?.textColor = UIColor.red;
    return cell
}
```

cell.detailTextLabel?.text is taking the old value of postData2. Since in postData2 first index value is 38.

I think you got it.

**Solution:**

Never create two arrays to handle data. You can create one array of dictionaries to handle data. In your case it is currentpostDataArray and postData2.

I will modify the code with single array of dictionaries.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    setUpSearchBar()


    ref = Database.database().reference() //set the firebase reference

    // Retrieve the post and listen for changes
    databaseHandle = ref?.child("Posts2").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        // Code to execute when a child is added under "Posts"
        postData.removeAll()
        postData2.removeAll()
        tableDataArray.removeAll()

        for child in snapshot.children {
            let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
            let key = snap.key
            let value = String(describing: snap.value!)
            let rating = (value as NSString).integerValue

            postData.append(key)
            postData2.append(value)

            tableDataArray.append(tableData(boothName: key, boothRating: rating))
            currentpostDataArray = tableDataArray
        }

        self.tableView.reloadData()


    })

}

 // cellForRowAtIndexpath

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel?.text = currentpostDataArray[indexPath.row]. boothName
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = currentpostDataArray[indexPath.row]. boothRating + " ♥"
    cell.detailTextLabel?.textColor = UIColor.red;
    return cell
}

//searchBar delegate

    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    currentpostDataArray = tableDataArray
    for item in tableDataArray {
        let str = item.boothName
        if str.lowercased().range(of: searchText) != nil {
            currentpostDataArray.append(item)
        }
    }


    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Ok i got it so what is the appropriate code to update postData2? I'm quite new to this sorry

Comment: yea about that, my boothRating is in Int and the detailTextLabel only accepts String value :/

Comment: so what is the problem.

Comment: convert it to string:

Comment: cell.detailTextLabel?.text = String(currentpostDataArray[indexPath.row]. boothRating) + " ♥"

Comment: ok btw bro, should i change my var currentpostDataArray = [tableData]() or var currentpostDataArray = [String]() ? https://ibb.co/hWAQum

Comment: hmm idk why but when i changed cell.detailTextLabel?.text = String(currentpostDataArray[indexPath.row]. boothRating) + " ♥", everything froze, like i couldn't search for anything, it also couldn't filter by descending order in "Top 10".

Comment: Do one thing add breakpoint and check what is the value of currentpostDataArray in func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) before  tableView.reloadData()

Comment: Hey bro, i managed to sort of do it already, but there's just 1 more little problem. For the search bar, i have to enter the entire booth name before it can return the booth name and result to me. Is there a way to make it like if i search "Eco", it will display "EcoBooth" without having to type it all. Do look at the 4 photos for more reference. https://ibb.co/hLD0x6
https://ibb.co/jNNhAR
https://ibb.co/nv8NAR
https://ibb.co/jjw9qR

Comment: if searchText.lowercased().range(of:str) != nil {  change it to if str.lowercased().range(of:searchText) != nil {

Comment: Gosh thank you so much bro, really appreciate your help and time in resolving this!

Comment: its my pleasure to help you. Any problem ask me I will always ready to help you.

Comment: Hey bro just wanna ask you, because i have one tab/scope which shows "Top 10", so how do u only show the 10 cells?

Comment: You can check it out over here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48088221/uitableview-only-display-10-cells-rows-swift-xcode , i just posted it :)