# UITableView only display 10 cells/rows

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have two scopes/tabs on my TableViewController, "All" & "Top 10". I only want my "Top 10" tab to display only 10 cells/rows instead of displaying everything. Do look at my images for better references.

P.S: My UITableView is used to display real-time results of over 30 booths for my event using firebase database. Also, case 0 is "All", case 1 is "Top 10".

TableViewController

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseDatabase

var ref: DatabaseReference?
var databaseHandle: DatabaseHandle?
var postData = [String]()
var postData2 = [String]()
var currentpostDataArray = [String]()
var tableDataArray = [tableData]()
var tableDataArray2 = [tableData]()
var searchArray = [tableData]()
var selectedTab = 0

class TableViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchBarDelegate {


    @IBOutlet var searchBar: UISearchBar!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setUpSearchBar()

        ref = Database.database().reference()//set the firebase reference

            databaseHandle = ref?.child("Posts2").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
                // Code to execute when a child is added under "Posts"
                postData.removeAll()
                postData2.removeAll()
                tableDataArray.removeAll()


                for child in snapshot.children {
                    let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
                    let key = snap.key
                    let value = String(describing: snap.value!)
                    let rating = (value as NSString).integerValue

                    postData.append(key)
                    postData2.append(value)

                    tableDataArray.append(tableData(boothName: key, boothRating: rating))
                    currentpostDataArray = postData
                }

                self.tableView.reloadData()


            })

        databaseHandle = ref?.child("Posts2").queryOrderedByValue().queryLimited(toLast: 10).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            // Code to execute when a child is added under "Posts"
            postData.removeAll()
            postData2.removeAll()
            tableDataArray2.removeAll()


            for child in snapshot.children {
                let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
                let key = snap.key
                let value = String(describing: snap.value!)
                let rating = (value as NSString).integerValue

                postData.append(key)
                postData2.append(value)

                tableDataArray2.append(tableData(boothName: key, boothRating: rating))
                currentpostDataArray = postData
            }

            self.tableView.reloadData()


        })

    }


    private func setUpSearchBar() {
        searchBar.delegate = self
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return currentpostDataArray.count
    }




    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

        cell.textLabel?.text = currentpostDataArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = postData2[indexPath.row] + " ♥"
        cell.detailTextLabel?.textColor = UIColor.red;
        return cell
    }


    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        switch searchBar.selectedScopeButtonIndex {
        case 0:
            selectedTab = 0
            searchArray.removeAll()
            searchArray = tableDataArray
            currentpostDataArray.removeAll()
            postData2.removeAll()
            if !searchText.isEmpty {
                for data in searchArray {
                    let item = data.boothName
                    if (item.lowercased().range(of: searchText.lowercased()) != nil)
                    {
                        currentpostDataArray.append(data.boothName)
                        let value = String(describing: data.boothRating)
                        postData2.append(value)
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                loadDara()
            }
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        case 1:
            selectedTab = 1
            searchArray.removeAll()
            searchArray = tableDataArray2
            currentpostDataArray.removeAll()
            postData2.removeAll()
            if !searchText.isEmpty {
                for data in searchArray {
                    let item = data.boothName
                    if (item.lowercased().range(of: searchText.lowercased()) != nil)
                    {
                        currentpostDataArray.append(data.boothName)
                        let value = String(describing: data.boothRating)
                        postData2.append(value)
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                loadDara2()
            }
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        default:
            break
        }
    }


    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, selectedScopeButtonIndexDidChange selectedScope: Int) {
        switch selectedScope {
        case 0:
            currentpostDataArray.removeAll()
            postData2.removeAll()
            for data in tableDataArray {
                currentpostDataArray.append(data.boothName)

                let value = String(describing: data.boothRating)
                postData2.append(value)
            }
            self.tableView.reloadData()

        case 1:
            currentpostDataArray.removeAll()
            postData2.removeAll()
            let sortedTableData = tableDataArray2.sorted(by: { $0.boothRating > $1.boothRating })
            for data in sortedTableData {
                currentpostDataArray.append(data.boothName)

                let value = String(describing: data.boothRating)
                postData2.append(value)
            }
            self.tableView.reloadData()

        default:
            break

        }
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    func loadDara() {
        for data in tableDataArray {
            currentpostDataArray.append(data.boothName)

            let value = String(describing: data.boothRating)
            postData2.append(value)
        }

    }

    func loadDara2() {
        let sortedTableData = tableDataArray2.sorted(by: { $0.boothRating > $1.boothRating })
        for data in sortedTableData {
            currentpostDataArray.append(data.boothName)

            let value = String(describing: data.boothRating)
            postData2.append(value)
        }
    }

}

class tableData {
    var boothName: String
    var boothRating: Int
    init(boothName: String, boothRating: Int) {
        self.boothName = boothName
        self.boothRating = boothRating
    }
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: What have you done while clicking segment(Top 10)?

Comment: i filter the "Top 10" by the number of hearts in descending order. So the most hearts will be at the top while the least hearts at the bottom.

Comment: so you now need only 10 cells from that sorted list.?

Comment: Yes correct please help me

Comment: ok few minutes :) :)

Comment: @Moritz sorry about that

Comment: alright copy that. Would you mind helping me with my error?

Comment: no it works but then there's a slight error afterwards. it's related

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare a variable in your view controller pointing to which segment is selected

```
var selectedTab = 0
```

In `selectedScopeButtonIndexDidChange`, assign value to above variable based on selection change:

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, selectedScopeButtonIndexDidChange selectedScope: Int) {
            switch selectedScope {
            case 0:
                selectedTab = 0
                currentpostDataArray.removeAll()
                postData2.removeAll()
                for data in tableDataArray {
                    currentpostDataArray.append(data.boothName)

                    let value = String(describing: data.boothRating)
                    postData2.append(value)
                }
                self.tableView.reloadData()

            case 1:
                selectedTab = 1
                currentpostDataArray.removeAll()
                postData2.removeAll()
                let sortedTableData = tableDataArray.sorted(by: { $0.boothRating > $1.b

oothRating })
            for data in sortedTableData {
                currentpostDataArray.append(data.boothName)

                let value = String(describing: data.boothRating)
                postData2.append(value)
            }
            self.tableView.reloadData()

        default:
            break

        }
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

In `numberOfRowsInSection`, check for selected segment and set row count:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            if selectedTab = 0 {
              return currentpostDataArray.count
            } else {
              if currentpostDataArray.count >= 10 {
                return 10
              } else {
                return currentpostDataArray.count
              }
            }
 }
```

Comment: apparently it doesn't work, still remains the same :(

Comment: its ok bro, i managed to create another array for "Top 10" tab instead. everything works fine except that when i first start up the app and tap on the result page, the "All" tab will display the top 10 booths, and when i tap on the "Top 10" tab and back to the "All" tab, it will display all the results. You can look at the 3 images for better reference. ibb.co/k4SChG ibb.co/gLvyNG ibb.co/fxayNG

Comment: Do look at my updated code above for better reference also :)

Comment: It's ok! i managed to solve it already, thanks for helping out though :)

Comment: Your updated code was not done as per my code... selectedTab = 0 or 1 value should be set in selectedScopeButtonIndexDidChange, not in textDidChange. If you had implemented my code of selectedScopeButtonIndexDidChange, it would have worked. My solution was correct.

Comment: thanks bro, i managed to do yours instead as mine was abit messy. But there's just 1 more little problem i hope you could help me with. when a value from any booth increments in my realtime Database, the "Top 10" tab will be arranged in the "All" order. Do look at my updated codes and images for more reference :(. This is my last error for my app https://ibb.co/hJSS6m
https://ibb.co/jM8Zmm
https://ibb.co/iaffRm

Answer (score 0):

After sorting your **tableDataArray**, you should create an array with the first 10 elements from **tableDataArray**

Comment: Hey man, i did like u what u asked, i did another array "tableDataArray2", everything works fine except that when i first start up the app and tap on the result page, the "All" tab will display the top 10 booths, and when i tap on the "Top 10" tab and back to the "All" tab, it will display all the results. You can look at the 3 images for better reference. https://ibb.co/k4SChG
https://ibb.co/gLvyNG
https://ibb.co/fxayNG

Comment: It's ok! i managed to solve it already, thanks for helping out though :)

Comment: I'm sorry for not answering before now but I was sleeping. It was night over here :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement your logic as you change the index of your **segmentControl**.Set a tag variable as the index of segment changes and reload your table view once again. In your codes you have returned all the cells in your table view whatever the Segmentindex becomes.

You can try this and if you feel confused feel free to comment below:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
class SegmentViewController : UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource
{
    @IBOutlet weak var uiSegmentControl: UISegmentedControl!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    var tag : Int = 1
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tableView.delegate = self
        self.tableView.dataSource = self
    }


    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if tag == 1
        {  //return total count
            return 100
        }
        else if tag == 2
        {
            return 10
        }
        return 0
        }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as! UITableViewCell
        cell.textLabel?.text = "CEll"
        return cell
    }


    @IBAction func didchange(_ sender: Any) {
        if uiSegmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1
        {
          print("Segment 1 is selected")
            self.tag = 2
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
        else
        {
            print("Segment 2 is selected")
             self.tag = 1
            self.tableView.reloadData()

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Code only answers are not useful. Explain what was wrong in the original question and explain how this answer fixes the problem.

Comment: Hey bro, i managed to create another array for "Top 10" tab instead. everything works fine except that when i first start up the app and tap on the result page, the "All" tab will display the top 10 booths, and when i tap on the "Top 10" tab and back to the "All" tab, it will display all the results. You can look at the 3 images for better reference. ibb.co/k4SChG ibb.co/gLvyNG ibb.co/fxayNG

Comment: Do look at my updated code above for better reference also :)

Comment: It's ok! i managed to solve it already, thanks for helping out though :))

Answer (score 0):

You need to customize when data appending in `loadDara2` function.

```
func loadDara2() {
    let sortedTableData = tableDataArray.sorted(by: { $0.boothRating > $1.boothRating })
    for data in sortedTableData {
        currentpostDataArray.append(data.boothName)

        let value = String(describing: data.boothRating)
          if (postData2.count != 10){
               postData2.append(value)
            }else {
              break
         }
    }
}
```

This will help.

Comment: Hey bro, i managed to create another array for "Top 10" tab instead. everything works fine except that when i first start up the app and tap on the result page, the "All" tab will display the top 10 booths, and when i tap on the "Top 10" tab and back to the "All" tab, it will display all the results. You can look at the 3 images for better reference. ibb.co/k4SChG ibb.co/gLvyNG ibb.co/fxayNG

Comment: Do look at my updated codes above for better reference also :)

Comment: It's ok! i managed to solve it already, thanks for helping out though :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a outlet of segment control and connect it.

```
@IBOutlet weak var segment: UISegmentedControl!
```

Now replace **numberOfRowsInSection** method with below code.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 ? currentpostDataArray.count : min(currentpostDataArray.count, 10)
}
```

Comment: Hey bro, i managed to create another array for "Top 10" tab instead. everything works fine except that when i first start up the app and tap on the result page, the "All" tab will display the top 10 booths, and when i tap on the "Top 10" tab and back to the "All" tab, it will display all the results. You can look at the 3 images for better reference. ibb.co/k4SChG ibb.co/gLvyNG ibb.co/fxayNG

Comment: It's ok! i managed to solve it already, thanks for helping out though :)